# Number of Triangles in a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, triangles, algebraic-graph-theory

One can show, that a Graph with at least $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, has at least $\dfrac{4m}{3n}(m-\dfrac{n^2}{4})$. I was wondering, about the best lowest bound of this, and the best upper bound of this ( is the best upper bound truly, the number of triangles formed in the complete graph , i.e $ \Delta(G) \choose 3$ ?

Comment: Are you demanding the graph be simple?  If not, do you count three loops at the same vertex as a triangle?

Comment: Yes, I suppose its simple, my knowledge is limited at the moment around simple graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upper bound is $\frac 13{m \choose 2}=\frac {m(m-1)}6$ because at the most you can choose any two edges and have one triangle, then each triangle gets counted $3$ times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about the best lowest bound?

Comment: One lower bound is that the complete bipartite graph on $n$ vertices has $\frac {n^2}4$ edges and no triangles.  This supports the $(m-\frac {n^2}4)$ factor in your expression.  Now, if my image is correct, each edge you add adds $\frac n2$ triangles, so this approach gives $\frac n2(m-\frac {n^2}4)$ triangles.  I do not know if there is a way to have fewer.

Comment: I see yes..can you give more details about how you got the result? I have a more complex solution on my mind and yours seems more elegant..

Comment: I just imagined the complete bipartite graph.  You split the vertices into two groups of $\frac n2$ and connect all the vertices of one group to all the vertices of the other.  There are no triangles.  Now if you add an edge, you have to add it within a group.  The next sentence is a little wrong, but it is how I was thinking.  All the triangles containing that edge have one vertex from the other group, so each time you add an edge you add $\frac n2$.  This is true until you add more than $\frac n4$ edges, at which point you cannot avoid a triangle within the one side.

Comment: "This is achieved in a complete graph." If I understood correctly, this is incorrect, a complete graph has $O(m^{1.5})$ triangles

Comment: @user97678:  you are correct.  I was counting pairs of edges that do not meet.